# tagging server "Server Error" when trying to deploy Server Tag

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-tag-manager, server-tags

I'm trying to deploy manually GTM Server Container. I'm following this configuration guide from google:

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/serverside/script-user-guide

Everything seems to be working fine however when trying to preview my container I have the following error

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

When I'm running the command in the cloud shell `gcloud app logs read` I have the following error `Error: Failed to decode the container config.`

Any idea? What can I do?

Comment: Did you check your container config string? It seems like you entered an incorrect value for container config while deploying your server. Are you deploying in standard environment or flexible environment?

Comment: when looking in the testing.yaml config I can a variable called CONTAINER_CONFIG which is the name I've entered during the setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might sound very obvious but if anyone if stuck the same way what you need to do is passing the Container Configuration code you get from the GTM interface to the Container config variable when setting up the server.

Comment: do you need that when automatically provisionning a tagging server?